# SpriteKit: Callback after all nodes finished actions

Tags: callback, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

Simplified problem (in Swift but I think also in Objective-C): I've got two nodes where actions have started. The information about the initial runtime of the action is not available (got lost). I'd like to be informed *after both actions* have been performed.

After performing additional actions will be assigned according to the current state (which is not available in advance).

Any simple solution known?

Comment: runaction withc completion block that increases counter ivar

Comment: This would require to run the completion block code and the SpriteKit action method in the same context/thread as instance variables may not be atomic. Is the same context/thread guaranteed or does Swift provide automatic synchronized access to instance variables?

Values ("let" expressions) will work fine but "var" definitions may not work.

Comment: if it turns out to be a problem (doubtful because actions don't seem to run in parallel) just create a atomic property and use that

Comment: I'll give it a try but in Swift are no atomic instance variables available. I thought of such kind of solution before but I felt it is flawed by design.

Comment: if swift doesn't offer synchronized access to a variable somehow i would consider the language flawed. ;) But i doubt that it's impossible, probably just not immediately obvious how to do it or maybe even implicitly hidden within the language design. Either way, at worst you have to create an objc class with that property and instantiate it in swift, no real loss there.

Comment: I'd expect Apple to update the language (as they did past the last weeks). Swift itself is nonetheless in some fields flawed but I think that is the burden of compatibility to ObjC.

Comment: I too expect synchronization/multithreading to be an upcoming swift update given how all modern iOS devices are multiprocessor. But I doubt this will be in 8.0 if it's not already in the most recent beta.